# How do I symbolically integrate functions in matlab where I know the output must contain bessel functions?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, symbolic-integration

I am working with the following function:

f(x) = a*(1+cos(3*x)) where a is constant/parameter.

y(x) = exp(-b*f(x)) where b is another constant.

I need to compute the definite integral integral(0,2pi)y(x)dx.

I am trying to implement another research paper for our research group. I know the output must contain modified bessel functions of the first kind which are functions of 'a'. Matlab simply refuses to evaluate this integral.

The following is my code(Matlab):

```
syms x;
syms a;
syms b;

f_x = a*(1+cos(3*x));
y_x = exp(-b*f_x);
z_x = int(y_x, x, 0, 2*pi)
```

Output:

```
Warning: Explicit integral could not be found. 

z_x =

int(1/exp(a*b*(cos(3*x) + 1)), x = 0..2*pi)
```

Request your assistance in solving this! I am sure that the integral contains bessel functions like I(a), etc. at many places. Is there any pre-processing I need to do here?  I kind of need this solution urgently. I appreciate quick responses which can atleast point in the right direction.

Comment: Well, IF they are functions of a, then they SHOULD be functions of a*b, since a only appears directly as a*b in the expression. Regardless, Alpha also fails here.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!. It worked in mathematica, failed in Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

Starting R2017b, this works. Use [int](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/int.html).

```
>> syms x;
syms a;
syms b;

f_x = a*(1+cos(3*x));
y_x = exp(-b*f_x);
z_x = int(y_x, x, 0, 2*pi)

z_x =
2*pi*exp(-a*b)*besselj(0, a*b*1i)
```